# How to customize the size of the bar in a TabbedPage? [XAMARIN.FORMS]

Tags: c#, xamarin, height, tabbed

I have a Tabbed Page, I have it already accommodated, but I feel that it is very small and I need the lower bar to be higher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Mobile.View.Principal"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile.View"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            BarTextColor="{StaticResource Gris}"
            BarBackgroundColor="white">
    
    
    <local:Inicio Title="Inicio" Icon="home_icon.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30"/>
    <local:Consultas Title="Consultas" Icon="search_icon.png"/>
    <local:Utilidades Title="Utilidades" Icon="settings_icon.png"/>
    <local:Perfil Title="Perfil" Icon="favorites_icon.png"/>
    
</TabbedPage>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
public partial class Principal : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
{
    public Principal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor(Color.Black);
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarItemColor(Color.LightGray);
        //On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().DisableSwipePaging(); //Disable sliding the pages with your finger.
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);  // Hide nav bar
    }

    async void OnPerfilAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Perfil());
    }
}
```

and that's how the app looks:

[image]

**HOW IS THE NAME OF THE BAR HEIGHT PROPERTY?**

I need some help!!!

Answer (score 3):

On which platform do you want to change it? You will likely need to implement a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for each platform that you want to make this change.

For iOS, you can add a new general class file to the iOS project named `MyTabbedPageRenderer`. Then in the file, add this line above the `namespace` declaration:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage), typeof(YourNamespace.MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
```

where `YourNamespace` is the namespace that `MyTabbedPageRenderer` is in, i.e. the namespace just below where you have this attribute

Now make the class inherit from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TabbedRenderer`, e.g.:

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TabbedRenderer
```

Then add the following override method to the class:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        var newHeight = TabBar.Frame.Height + 50;
        CoreGraphics.CGRect tabFrame = TabBar.Frame; //self.TabBar is IBOutlet of your TabBar
        tabFrame.Height = newHeight;
        tabFrame.Y = View.Frame.Size.Height - newHeight;
        TabBar.Frame = tabFrame;
    }
```

The above will increase the Tabbar height on iOS by 50 pixels from the default. Change the `50` to whatever value you like.

And for Android, you actually do not need to make a custom renderer since there is an Android layout that you can set a `minHeight` for the TabLayout. To do this, open the Tabbar.axml file in the resources/layout folder in your Android project. Then add an `android:minHeight` attribute to the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` element:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    ...
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    />
```

This sets the height to a fixed 300 pixels. Set it to whatever you want.

Alternately you can set the height in the `MainActivity.OnCreate` method. The below is starting from a template Xam.Forms `TabbedPage` project. Put the following after the `LoadApplication(new App())` call:

```
Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout tabBar = FindViewById<Android.Support.Design.Widget.TabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
tabBar.SetMinimumHeight(300);
```

Change the `Resource.Id` to whatever the `android:id` is for the `TabLayout` in the Tabbar.axml file

Comment: 2021 Update: There is no more 'resources/layout' folder. This does not work anymore for android